# How to lag by number of days with a group by function in Python

Tags: python, offset

I'm trying to create a lag variable based off a defined number of days, but have not found a viable solution. In my real world example, there is not a 1 to 1 translation between rows and dates, so I'm unable to use a basic shift function.

The example data frame below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':np.repeat(pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-01-04'), 2),
                   'id_var':np.tile(['a', 'b'], 4),
```

This was my attempt, but this does not return the intended results when I'm creating a new column

```
df['lag'] = df.set_index('dt').groupby('id_var')['value'].shift(2, 'D')
```

This is the correct output for what I'm trying to accomplish ('lag' column).

```
df['lag'] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(df)
```